# react-native-gesture-handle swipeable methods not accessible with functional components

Tags: react-native, this, react-functional-component, react-native-gesture-handler

The React-Native-Gesture-Handler [docs](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/component-swipeable/#close) show Swipeable methods implemented in JS classes and only being accessible by the "this" keyword e.g. **this.close**

Example from docs:

```
...
<RectButton style={styles.leftAction} onPress={this.close}>
...
```

How do I use the "this" keyword (or its alternative) in React functional components to access these methods?

Comment: I think you need something like **ref**.

Answer (score 1):

Use Ref in this case:

```
const YourComponent = () => {

    const swipeRef = React.useRef()

    const closeSwipable = () => {
        swipeRef?.current?.close()
    }

    return (
        <Swipeable ref={swipeRef}>
        </Swipeable>
    )
}
```

Comment: Should be accepted as the answer.